# Change HTML5 video’s quality from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

In YouTube, we can change the quality of the video from a dropdown like 360p, 144p, 240p, etc. Can we do the same with HTML5 video element from JavaScript?

Comment: Sure, if you have multiple files with different quality you can just swap the source.

Comment: so, do you mean youtube keeps multiple files of the same video, but i dont think so, since i own a youtube channel and i posted only one file, but i can still swap the quality

Comment: @tenstar: believe it or not, the YouTube guys have figured out how to take your original video file, and convert it to different resolutions. I've heard rumours that they use *computers* for this.

Comment: @tenstar - that's exactly what they do. They convert your file into different resolutions etc. and when you click the button what happens is pretty much exactly what Quentin wrote below.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Manual selection of quality is just a matter of:

1. Saving the `currentTime` in a variable
2. setting the video `src` to the URL of a different video (with the same content at a different quality)
3. Setting the `currentTime` to the value in the variable
4. Playing the video

Comment: This, but after changing the source, you should call `video.load()` to tell the browser that the sources have changed.

Comment: Hej did like that but after I changed the quality of the video after few second in iphone the video started from the begining not from the current time here is my thread : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61663311/change-video-quality-using-jquery  can you check this?

Answer (score 2):

You want to use the **youtube-api** with **html5-player** or you are using video files on your server?
if youtube-api, try:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

**[edit]**

The `javascript` or `actionscript` only access different videos, as they do not have exchanged the quality would have to recompile in real time (which is unfeasible).

Do you happen to be interested, you can use **ffmpeg** on your server (or before you upload the videos to your desktop) to generate various formats (qualities) of video, you can study the following link:
http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/Creating%20multiple%20outputs

hope this helps.

Comment: the "youtube" generates several videos with different qualities from your original video. The javascript or actionscript only access different videos, as they do not have exchanged the quality would have to recompile in real time (which is unfeasible). Consider the response of @Quentin.