# HTML5 Video Quality Selector Plugin

Tags: html, video, plugins

I'm sure I'm not the first, but is it possible to, using jQuery, javascript...etc, add a quality selector to the HTML5 Video tag?  I know this is possible by changing the source, but I don't want to do that.  Is there a plugin that someone made for this?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried googling? :P
Taken from [Change HTML5 video’s quality from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17614660/javascript-change-html5-videos-quality):

Manual selection of quality is just a matter of:

Saving the currentTime in a variable

setting the video src to the URL of a different video (with the same content at a different quality)

Setting the currentTime to the value in the variable

Playing the video

Comment: Yeah, already saw that.  I need something like a plugin that can do this.  I am already implementing that method, but I find that very inconvenient.