# Change video quality using jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5-video

I have a simple video player now I would like to change the quality of the video as on youtube, after changing the video source it should start exactly like the current time, **IT SHOULD NOT START FROM 0** (IPHONE PROBLEM).

Here I what I have so far

HTML

```
<div id="video-container">
    <video id="videoplayer" width="750" height="421" webkit-playsinline 
    </video>
</div>

<select class="qualitypick" autocomplete="off"> </select>
```

**Now on android, chrome, edge etc works fine as expected but when I open the demo on iPhone safari, I play the video after few seconds I change to low quality, but the video starts from the beginning instead of starting at the current time.**

What is wrong with the code above? any help or suggestions will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

If it doesn't work, try this

```js
var videoDOM = '';
var curtime = '';
var source = '';
var vide0 = '';

var formats = {
```

deomill.pl/editorv1/molecular_player/quality/molecular_360_converted.mp4",

```
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    for (var format in formats) {
        $('.qualitypick').append($("<option value='" + format + "'>" + format + "</option>"));
    }

    $('.qualitypick').change(function () {
        video = document.getElementById("videoplayer");
       curtime = video.currentTime;
        video.src = formats[$(this).val()];
        video.currentTime = curtime; 
        video.play();
    })

})
```

This worked on my windows computer